# Rails 7 - has_many_attached delete old attachment when new is loaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-7

I'v got problem with Active Storage under Rails 7.

I read some posts but all are about Rails 5-6 and some methods was depreciated since then.

Problem - when I try to upload second photo, old is deleted. Why? How to fix this?

I have model:

```
class Profile
  has_many_attached :photos
  has_one_attached :avatar
```

in controller:

```
 class ProfilesController < ApplicationController

 

 def update

    Rails.logger.debug params.inspect
    @profile = current_user.profile

    @profile.update(profiles_params)


 private
# Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
def profiles_params
    params.require(:profile).permit(:id, :email, :marketing, 
                                    :marketing_second, :terms, 
                                    :personal_data, 
                                    :birthdate, :avatar, :photos )
end
```

in view:

```
<%= form_for @profile do |f| %>  

    <div class='upload_container'>

       <%= f.file_field :photos, accept:'image/*', 
          :class=>'file_field_custom',  required: true  %>
       <%= f.button "Upload", type:'submit', :class=>'photos_submit_button' %>

    </div>

<% end %>
```

This was removed from Rails 7:

```
config.active_storage.replace_on_assign_to_many = false
```

logs:

```
#<ActionController::Parameters {"_method"=>"patch",
```

"authenticity_token"=>"y5n4UgRhRWFB9Q0L3J1roxK3dhuijRQk7Fng6sjHU52G0KDs9OJlYt8nmshG8HYnlrk7JB9x3QHDO8_GQnDwsA", "profile"=>{"photos"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007f9773f3db78 @tempfile=#Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20230119-3094-gapmw4.jpg, @original_filename="saturn-planet-3200-1200-1966.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name="profile[photos]"; filename="saturn-planet-3200-1200-1966.jpg"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}, "controller"=>"profiles", "action"=>"update", "id"=>"abcd"} permitted: false>
[1m[36mProfile Load (0.6ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT `profiles`.* FROM `profiles` WHERE `profiles`.`user_id` = 1 LIMIT 1[0m
↳ app/models/user.rb:59:in `profile'

```
 [1m[36mActiveStorage::Attachment Destroy (4.4ms)[0m  [1m[31mDELETE FROM 
`active_storage_attachments` WHERE `active_storage_attachments`.`id` = 334[0m
  ↳ app/controllers/profiles_controller.rb:133:in `update'
```

Why action Destroy is fired.

Comment: it is because you are uploading avatar and your model is configured to has_one_attached :avatar

Comment: https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#has-one-attached

Comment: sorry I paste wrong code

Comment: Does this help https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-upload-images-into-your-rails-project-using-active-storage-1285a69e4cf5

Comment: yep ... you can write answer - @profile.photos.attach(params[:profile][:photos]) in update controller attach files and do not delete old one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@profile.photos.attach(params[:profile][:photos])` in update action of your controller